# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/projectname/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am extremely new at Spring Security and am trying to learn it using tutorials. Now my application is giving a 404 error which I am unable to resolve. I tried looking at similar problems but that did not work out too. Can you please help me resolve this? The server shows this error:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc'
```

The page shows:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /test/. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
```

My web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name> TestApp</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

<!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

DispatcherServlet:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"     
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.controller.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

admin.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>

    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />

    <!-- csrt for log out-->
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
      <input type="hidden" 
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
        </h2>
    </c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page session="false"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>   
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

login.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Spring Security Custom Login Form (XML)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
          action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
package com.test.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Custom Login Form");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Custom Login Form");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

    //Spring Security see this :
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your security config,  (pattern="/admin**" )
You should try **/admin** to trigger spring security instead of /test

Comment: When I try /testsuite/admin, it goes to login page but the page is blank and same error for this page

Comment: @p19 In web.xml, the DispatcherServlet's contextConfigLocation should point to spring-mvc.xml not to spring-security.xml
    `<servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>`

Comment: I tried this too..same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The base package  declared in your *dispatcher servlet*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.arcsight.qa.perf.suite.web.controller.*" />
```

is *different* with the location where you put your controller classes :

*`com.test.web.controller;`*

this is why it complained about

> *No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc'*

notice that *'test'* is referring to *`com.test.`*

If you want to scan all the classes under the *com* directory (including all of its subdirectories) just modify it to *`base-package="com"`*  (it's not a good practice, though) like so :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
```

Not related to your problems but make sure the following dependecies are existed :

- spring-security-config-x.x.x.RELEASE
- spring-security-core-x.x.x.RELEASE
- spring-security-web-x.x.x.RELEASE

Comment: That was a copy mistake here..Sorry, I have corrected it now.